# Calculate the area bounded by the curves: $y=\frac{1}{x^2}e^\frac{1}{x}, y=0, x=1, x =2$

Tags: calculus

**Question**

> Calculate the area bounded by the curves: $y=\frac{1}{x^2}e^\frac{1}{x}, y=0, x=1, x =2$

I was proposed to solve it with a Lambert function, but I am not allowed to, so the option below doesn't really count

$$x^2=e^{1/x}\implies x=\frac{1}{2W(1/2)}$$

$$I=2-\frac{1}{2W(1/2)}-\int_{\frac{1}{2W(1/2)}}^2\frac{1}{x^2}e^{1/x};dx$$

Also, I have an idea to do something like this:$$d(\frac{1}{x})=\frac{-dx}{x^2}$$

But I have no idea how I can move on with it.

I'd also be very thankful if someone were to have a complete answer
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: The bounds in the title are different from the bounds in your question.  The title question is much easier.

Comment: Sorry, my bad the title question is the right one, I'll make an edit

Comment: Then the limits of integration are $1$ and $2$.  It makes the integral an easy $u$-substitution.

Comment: Could you please solve it for me, because I've tried several times without success

Comment: You should post what you've tried.  You have the correct substitution in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact solution being only available in terms of Lambert function, we can only have approximations. I also discard any root-finding method.

For conveniency, consider that we look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=x^2 e^{-1/x} -1$$ By inspection, the solution is $\in (1,2)$.

Performin a series expansion around $x=1$, we have
$$f(x)=\left(\frac{1}{e}-1\right)+\frac{3 (x-1)}{e}+\frac{5 (x-1)^2}{2
   e}+O\left((x-1)^3\right)$$ Neglecting the high order terms, solving the quadratic gives as an estimate
$$x=\frac{2+\sqrt{10 e-1}}{5} =1.42338\cdots$$ which is not bad since the exact value
$$\frac{1}{2 W\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}=1.42153$$ So, the relative error is $0.130$%.

We can do better solving at most quadratic equations. Instead of series, using the $[2,2]$ Padé approximant
$$x^2 e^{-1/x}=\frac 1e \,\,\frac{1+\frac{395 }{138}(x-1)+\frac{1777}{828}
   (x-1)^2 }{1-\frac{19 }{138}(x-1)+\frac{49}{828} (x-1)^2}$$ gives
$$x=\frac{1184-212 e+\sqrt{-268524+6588072 e-149292 e^2}}{3554-98 e}=1.42178$$ whose relative error is $0.017$%.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{\frac{1}{2W(1/2)}}^{2}\frac{1}{x^2}e^{1/x}dx=-\int_{\frac{1}{2W(1/2)}}^{2}e^{1/x}d1/x=-\int_{\frac{1}{2W(1/2)}}^{2}de^{1/ x}$$

Then use the Newton-Leibniz formula.

Let $t$ denote the solution of$x^2=e^{1/x}$.

The leftside$=\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{1}{x^2}e^{1/x}dx=1$,

rightside$=(2-t)-\int_{t}^{2}\frac{1}{x^2}e^{1/x}dx=(2-t)+e^{1/2}-e^{1/t}=2+e^{1/2}-t+t^2.$

Then the areas$=3+e^{1/2}-t+t^2.$

$x^2=e^{1/x}$may not have an analytical solution,at least im unable to do.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I still don't have a clue how to solve it